# What is the most minimal C++ program

Tags: c++

Is there a **more minimal** C++ program than

```
int main(){}
```

which is semantically correct?

**Note:** I am not looking for a shared object.

Comment: What's the point of this question?

Comment: what's minimal? that does not do anything. You can do nothing with nothing.

Comment: @AndrewL L : The question is self descriptive so can't explain further.

Comment: @madmik3 : It is not necessary that the program accomplish something..

Comment: I'm curious because this bit of knowledge is useless. There's no point in asking this. It's a waste of time

Comment: wouldnt `void main() {}` be more minimal because it doesnt return anything?

Comment: @Stephen The return type of main *must* be int. Everything else is not standard C++ (and void has 1 char more than int)

Comment: @AndrewL, the program is useless as a user program. However, it might be useful to a compiler writer. They must be able to build and execute the program.

Comment: Relevant: [simplest "correct" program in various languages](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Empty_program#C.2B.2B).

Comment: @MooseBoys : Apprecitate the link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a more minimal program than

```
int main(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a hosted implementation `int main(){}` is minimal.

A freestanding implementation can support other startup functions such as `z`, in which case `int z(){}` (or whatever letter) could be minimal if the standard allows such startup function to have a default return value; I'm not 100% sure of that.

All assuming you want the shortest source code.

Comment: Actually never thought of a freestanding implementation while asking the question. Anyways thanks for the info.. I have never used a freestanding implementation so far, but I guess they relevant in places where memory is sparse..